# Can I connect to a Facebook app with my page profile?

Tags: facebook, api

I tried, but it always tries to redirect me to my personal account

The app belongs to me. I created it with my personal account. I would like to let companies connect to the app with their page accounts, not as people - it would be more convenient for brands that way.

To test it, I created my own page, and tried to register myself as an app user with, but it did not work.

Comment: Are you trying to create an app through business account, or do you want to add your app as a page tab ?

Comment: @AnveshSaxena see the updated info

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect to a Facebook app as a Page or through business account as for some reason Facebook doesn't allows you to connect applications with the business account or Page. You can't even [like a page](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/142035825943309?browse=search_51b705af0f27c2669849813) using the [like box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) if you are using business account.